# How do I make an AutoHotkey script work in a VMware virtual machine only?

Tags: windows-7, windows, autohotkey, vmware-workstation

I'm running VMware Workstation 9 on Windows 7 and I wonder how do I make an AutoHotkey script (which does some key remapping) work only when the input is grabbed by a VMware virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, VMware
    a::b
    c::d
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the windows title in the script is not necessarily to be the full window title of your virtual machine, making it simply `VMware` works for any VM window.

Comment: @Desmond, I changed the script to include the SetTitleMatchMode to 2, so any window with `VMWare` in the title will work.